# Get attribute_code or attribute_id in layered catalog\layer\view.phtml

Tags: layered-navigation

I used a [Layered Navigation SEO](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html) to make my layered navigation to have a multiselect on filter and AJAX updater result and layered navigation. Every filter in layered navigation is in [Bootstrap 3 collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). The problem is that when user extend a filter and select something, layered navigation is reloaded by AJAX request and every field is collapsed, witch is annoying.

I want to make some customization on that and add to each filter some unique HTML attribute like `data-attribute-code` and add some info about witch collapse are extend, so I can set then to be extended when layered navigation is reloaded. 
Current problem that i have is that i can get only the name of the filter with `$_filter->getName()` witch is not good to use like identification for filter. But when i try to get a attribute code or id i get empty stings. I try with this code

```
$_filter->getId();
$_filter->getCode();
$_filter->getAttributeId();
$_filter->getAttributeCode();
```

If someone can help me and show how to get attribute ID or Code i will be very thankful.

Answer (score 8):

This will give the `attribute code`:

```
$_filter->getRequestVar();
```

You can get attribute id by using the following:

```
// $attributeCode = YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE; 
// In your case it will be as below:
$attributeCode = $_filter->getRequestVar();

$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                ->setCodeFilter($attributeCode)
                ->getFirstItem();

$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :

```
 <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
     <?php $attributemode = $_filter->getAttributeModel();
         if($attributemode){
             echo $attributeCode = $attributemode->getAttributeCode();
         } ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This give you attribute code.